# How to convert .mat file to .xml file?

Tags: xml, matlab, opencv

I want to use some models trained through DPM algorithm under MATLAB,but I need to convert its format from .mat to .xml so that I can transfer the models under OpenCV environment.if there are some critical functions to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to store one or several variables as XML files. This can probably be achieved with the [File Exchange XML Toolbox](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4278-xml-toolbox)

```
str=xml_format(project,'off')
```

If desired, you can [combine all variables in your workspace to a struct](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36257-save-workspace-to-struct) before using this function, to easily get them into a single XML file.

---

Note that it appears this only works with Matlab versions older than 2016a.

Comment: Thank you for point out that. I have solved this through matlab2015b. BTW, if someone wants the code, just contact me.

Comment: @Cherishtttz One of the main purposes of this site is to help future visitors, therefore I would recommend you to post an answer with the solution that you created. (And perhaps a little explanation)

Comment: Ok, thank you.but it's  not a simple answer, So I'm trying to edit it into a document, and then I will post it.